# How to determine if these vectors are optimal points

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, vector-analysis

Let :
$$f(\mathrm{x}) = \frac{1}{4}\|\mathrm{A - xx^T\|_F,A\succ  0,x\in R^n}$$
where $\| \cdot \|_F$ is the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm).
Please calculate all critical points that satisfy $\nabla f(\mathrm{x}) = 0$, and determine if they are optimal points.

Now I have obtained the following equation:
$$\nabla f(\mathrm{x}) = \mathrm{(xx^T-A)x}$$
$$\nabla^2f(\mathrm{x}) = 2\mathrm{x}\mathrm{x}^T+\mathrm{x}^T\mathrm{x}\cdot I-A$$

I already know that $\nabla f(\mathrm{x}) = 0$ means $\mathrm{x} = 0$ or $\mathrm{x}$ is an eigenvector of A.

But I can't tell if the Hessian matrix is positive definite after these eigenvectors are substituted into the Hessian matrix.

Comment: What norm are we talking about?

Comment: $||A|| ^2= \mathrm{tr(A^TA)}$